# sethours in NSDateComponents

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to sethours in NSDateComponents, I wrote the following code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComps setDay:intDay];
[dateComps setMonth:intMonth];
[dateComps setYear:intYear];
[dateComps setHour:intHoures];
[dateComps setMinute:intMinutes];

NSDate *itemDate;
itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

NSLog(@"reminder date: %@", itemDate);
```

but when I set the hours as 13, it sets it as 11. I want hours in 24 style. Anyone can help me in this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you NSLog an NSDate, you'll always see GMT. If you want to see the date in another time zone, you'll need to use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: could you please show me how to use timeZone here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time difference in the hours indicate that you might have problem with time zone, you could try to set the timezone for the date, I know `NSDateFormatter` has `timeZone` Property,I doubt if `NSDateComponents` have timeZone property. However you could set the timeZone for calendar

```
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: could you please show me sample code of how to use timeZone here?

Comment: I added it, it gives me 12 instead of 13 and 9 instead of 10.

Comment: I tried this `[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];` It solved my problem. Thanks for your help .. please update your answer to accept.